# Control rocket by angular velocity to target in 3D space

Tags: math, vector, 3d, game-physics, vectormath

My aim: control a rocket to target coordinates in 3d space

Data:

- target-position-vector (x, y, z)
- current-position-vector (x, y, z)
- current-direction-vector (x, y, z)

Problem: 
I just can manipulate the rocket's physic-body by linear velocity (thrust) and angular velocity (rotating).

Just able to set the start position/direction. After launch the ONLY control is rotating the missile by altering angular velocity. Furthermore, these rotation axis are locked in space, not relative to the rocket.

Before every frame is generated/rendered the velocities can be changed. I want the rocket to fly in a bow to the destination from every possible launch position.

I'm stuck at the fundamental concepts of converting current position-vector and direction-vector as well as target-vector to rotation of the rocket.

How to proceed?

How to calculate the angular velocities of the rocket on the flight path to target dependence on current position and direction?

more precise:

How to calculate in what direction the angular velocity has to set to minimize the delta between direction-vector and (target-vector - position-vector) = target-course-vector?

Comment: Can you actually set angular velocity or just angular acceleration? If it's the first, then you just want to turn with maximum velocity until missile direction and direction to target are lined up. If you can calculate the path ahead, just use an interpolation scheme with the start position, target position and start tangent vector.

Comment: I can actually set both. But in my mind angular velocity make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your approach makes sense. At my first attempt of implementation I use unit vectors of direction and target course. Hence the delta per axis as indicator of deviation of the course. As long as the deviation per axis is greater than 0 the angular velocity is set to 1, less than 0 to -1. It does work a bit. But not as well and it's not a proper mathematical interpolation. Do you have a specific conception of implementation?

Comment: It's probably a problem of Euler angles. They don't work well for velocities or other derivatives. Do you have the chance to switch the representation to either axis-angle, a matrix, or quaternion?